# Joomla 3 Cannot Shows Article Title

Tags: joomla, article

I am using Joomla 3 and wanted to show article title, by default I assume it should be shown. I tried Show/Use Global in Show Title but it is not working. WHY?

Answer (score 0):

Menu title could be enabled / disabled from articles configuration, article item and menu settings with the following priority:

```
1. Menus -> *Menu_Name -> *Menu_Item -> Options -> Show Title
2. Content -> Article Manager -> *Article_Name -> Options -> Show Title
3. Content -> Article Manager -> Options -> Articles -> Show Title
```

If it still doesn't show you have to check if you are using a template override for article page under:

```
templates/*your_template/html/com_content/article/default.php
```

And doesn't contain title display code:

```
<?php echo $this->escape($this->item->title); ?>
```